# Maximum product subsequence

Tags: algorithm

I need to find the maximum product of a subsequence in sequence of `n` integers.  I'm looking for an algorithm, not necessarily expressed as code.

Example:

1. In: 3,1,-2,4. Out: 4.
2. In: 2,5,-1,-2,-4. Out: 20. (2*5*-1*-2).

I've done an algorithm in `O(n²)`, but now I need one in `O(n)`.
I know that it's possible.

How can this be done in `O(n)`?

Comment: Since you don't want code this might be better for [Math.SE](http://math.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm O(n) is idealistic for average performance...

Comment: i dont understand this forum, if iask the code then somebody says to me that its wrong and says me to do it myself.
if i dos ask the code, its wrong too.

Comment: Didn't you know, you can't use SO unless you already know the answer to the question? ;-) Can you edit your answer please and paste in the code you used to get O(n^2) performance. I can't guarantee O(n) but I bet I could offer optimizations.

Comment: Sorry man, i've done the algorithm in a paper, but its the easy solution.

Comment: Its like take all possibles subsequence

Comment: @Shermano, Stack Overflow is for posting code questions to determine what is wrong with the code and/or how some piece of code works (with additional details on what makes a question good or bad). It is part of the [Stack Exchange](http://stackexchange.com/) Q&A sites. Since you are looking for algorithms, you can do as mwerschy said and go to the [Math Stack Exchange](http://math.stackexchange.com/) site, or you can go to the [Programmers Stack Exchange](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/) site, where you can get conceptual and algorithmic help (as opposed to questions about code itself).

Comment: @ajp15243, really? I mean, it's just wrong what you're saying. Math is for math, Programmers is for questions on profession and things. Algorithmic questions are totally on-topic here.

Comment: @unkulunkulu From comments and downvotes on SO, my understanding is that if the algorithm comes with code, then it's valid because there's code (and code needs an algorithm, after all), but if the question is *purely* about an algorithm, then SO isn't the best venue as SO is meant for code questions. I assume that the Programmers SE exists for this reason (also, the about page there says it is for "conceptual questions about software development", doesn't that include algorithms?). Maybe there's a part of SO that thinks purely algorithmic questions are fine, but that's not my understanding.

Comment: @unkulunkulu There are relevant MetaSO question threads [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/26339/are-algorithm-questions-allowed-on-so), [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/97869/are-questions-about-algorithms-on-topic), and [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173232/another-algorithm-question-closed-as-not-a-real-question). It's a tough question given those links, but this question is probably valid for SO since OP wants it for C in particular. Nonetheless, http://cs.stackexchange.com/ is probably the better alternative to Programmers for algorithm questions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If all your input was > 0, the maximum product would be found by multiplying all numbers together.

If all your input was non-0 and had an even count of negative numbers, again the maximum product would be found by multiplying all numbers together.

So the work is in dealing with zeros and negative numbers.

You need to through the list once, computing the running product as you go.
  If you reach a 0, then everything before that is a candidate subset and its particulars (start index, end index, product) needs to be saved should it be better than the best so far found.  Now start a new running product.
  If you reach a negative number, that item is a conditional break in your running total.
The running product without using the negative number would be assessed to your best.  But now you need to have 2 running products, the one with the negative number and a new one.  Thus subsequent multiplies need to work against 2 lists.  At this point I would have 2 running products.  Should you hit another negative number, each of your running list need to bisect as described beforehand.  So you could end up with lots of running lists if you did not prune.  I think you can prune the running lists to only keep track of 3: the sublist that just started, the continuing list with odd count of negative numbers and an even odd count of negative numbers.  Any candidate sub-list not part of the ongoing multiplication should be assesses to see it is the best before dropping it.

At the end its O(n)

Comment: Would this take into account sub-sequences that don't start and/or end next to zeros? Test cases: [1,2,0,-4,5,6,0,7,1] [1,2,0,-4,5,6,-1,-1,0,7,1]

Comment: @jhabbott I believe so.  For each time one encounters a negative, the currents running products being accumulated are assessed for stopping at that point.   In any case, the question does better fit other forums but it was fun for a little cross discipline thinking.

Answer (score 3):

The maximum subsequence product of a run of non-zero numbers is either the product of all the numbers (if there's an even number of negative numbers), or it's the greater of the product of all the numbers after the first negative number, and the product of all the numbers up to the last negative number.

This gives you an O(N) solution: break the sequence into runs of non-zero numbers and apply the rule in the first paragraph to each. Pick the max of these.

C-like Python code for this:

```
def prod(seq, a, b):
    r = 1
    for i in xrange(a, b):
        r *= seq[i]
    return r

def maxprodnon0(seq, a, b):
    firstneg = -1
    negs = 0
    for i in xrange(a, b):
        if seq[i] >= 0: continue
        negs += 1
        if firstneg < 0:
            firstneg = i
        lastneg = i
    if negs % 2 == 0: return prod(seq, a, b)
    return max(prod(seq, firstneg + 1, b), prod(seq, a, lastneg))

def maxprod(seq):
    best = 0
    N = len(seq)
    i = 0
    while i < N:
        while i < N and seq[i] == 0:
            i += 1
        j = i
        while j < N and seq[j] != 0:
            j += 1
        best = max(best, maxprodnon0(seq, i, j))
        i = j
    return best

for case in [2,5,-1,-2,-4], [1,2,0,-4,5,6,0,7,1], [1,2,0,-4,5,6,-1,-1,0,7,1]:
    print maxprod(case)
```

Comment: Nice simplification!  Some small things: It fails with [-3].  Maybe initialize with first number rather than 0.  Shouldn't `prod(seq, a, lastneg)` be `prod(seq, a, lastneg-1)`?  `prod(seq, a, b)` should not get called when a > b.  Note, overflow is a real code possibility.